# java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

I can't find the error activity where the error occurred ?

logcat of error from developer console---

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick (AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
  at android.view.View.performClick (View.java:5723)
  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run (View.java:22689)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:836)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:103)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:203)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6364)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1063)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:924)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at 
 android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick (AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
```